# Script to do a tcpdump and confirm two IPs communicating on same port

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, networking

Basically I'm trying to create a script in bash that will do a tcpdump on eth0 and look for two IP addresses communicating on the same port.

Ideally it would return a message saying "Bidirectional traffic confirmed" and output the two lines that are the same as a sort of "proof"

Otherwise it would return " Bidirectional traffic not confirmed "

I'm thinking this needs to be output to a file that can be parsed and have the stdout returned but I'm not sure.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
netstat -nap
```

This will display multiple columns but there are two very important ones. You have "Local Address" and "Foreign Address". This will show you if you are connected to an IP and what port.

Very quick script to see if this works could be...

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please input IP you are searching for" netInput
results=$(netstat -nap | grep ${netInput})
if [[ $(echo ${results} | grep -ic "established") != "0" ]] ; then
  echo "Bidirectional communication is established"
else
  echo "Bidirectional communication is NOT established"
fi
```

exit

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!

In most cases I'm not looking for a specific IP address, just in general confirming bidirectional communication. I also need to be able to specify the interface which I'm checking.

Comment: if you are not referring to a specific IP, than what exactly do you mean? Are you just trying to see if you have incoming traffic? When you say bidirectional, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: For example, I would want to do a tcpdump on eth0, look for two ip addresses communicating back and fourth on the same port:

1.1.1.1 22 > 2.2.2.2 24
2.2.2.2 24 > 1.1.1.1 22

The output i'm trying to achieve would be:

Bi-Directional traffic confirmed!
1.1.1.1 22 > 2.2.2.2 24
2.2.2.2 24 > 1.1.1.1 22

or

Bi-Directional traffic not found!